# Change stack navigation back button color in react native?

Tags: react-native

How can I change color of header navigation "back" button in react native. I am using stack navigation for this. Please check screenshot for more details.[screenshot Back Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XY3c1.jpg)

Comment: @Thanhal Thanks. headerTintColor is working fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to change react navigation's default back button Color on IOS header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45571716/is-there-a-way-to-change-react-navigations-default-back-button-color-on-ios-hea)

Comment: @Thanhal Yes that link have my answer.